# MySQL Python connector - Update not updating

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm using MySQL in Python but my update function isn't updating the row and I can't understand the message error.

```
def atualizaCartelaTabela(campo,valor,jogador):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='root',
                                     database='modular')
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        sql = """UPDATE Cartela 
                SET %s = %s
                WHERE PONTOS = %s"""
        atualiza = (campo,valor,jogador)
        cursor.execute(sql,atualiza)
    except Error as e:
        print("Erro ao atualizar campos da tabela Cartela ->", e)
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

def atualizaCartelaTabela(campo,valor,jogador):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='root',
                                     database='modular')
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        sql = """UPDATE Cartela 
                SET %s = %s
                WHERE PONTOS = %s"""
        atualiza = (campo,valor,jogador)
        cursor.execute(sql,atualiza)
    except Error as e:
        print("Erro ao atualizar campos da tabela Cartela ->", e)
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

atualizaCartelaTabela('Um',2,'Jogador 1')
```

The error I'm getting:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Um' = 2
> WHERE PONTOS = 'Jogador 1'' at line 2

And, this is the function used to create the table(working):

```
def criaTabelaCartela():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='root',
                                     database='modular')
        cursor = connection.cursor()  
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Cartela (PONTOS VARCHAR(10), Um int(2), Dois int(1), Tres int(1), Quatro int(1), Cinco int(1), Seis int(1), Full int(1), SequenciaBaixa int(1), Trinca int(1), Quadra int(1), SequenciaAlta int(1), Yahtzee int(1), PontuaçãoFinal int(1))")
        connection.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print("Erro ao criar tabela Cartela ->", e)
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

Comment: Your `actualize` creation should look like this i suppose =>  `atualiza = ('campo','valor','jogador')`

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat `campo`, `valor` and `jogador` are clearly variable names, and NOT the string values; so they should not be quoted. They are the parameters of the function `atualizaCartelaTabela`.

Comment: Btw, you've defined the `atualizaCartelaTabela()` function twice. Not sure which version we're supposed to see/use. In Python, the 2nd version defined later overrides the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at these 3 statements for what's causing the error:

```
sql = """UPDATE Cartela 
        SET %s = %s
        WHERE PONTOS = %s"""
atualiza = (campo,valor,jogador)
cursor.execute(sql,atualiza)
```

When you put `SET X = "y"` in the update query, the column name `X` cannot be parameterised. Only the values.

So the column name for `campo` should be substituted directly in the SQL string, not during `execute` - but note that this is UNSAFE. Change the first parameter to the `{}` notation for format and leave the values as `%s` so that they are parameters for `execute()`:

```
sql = """UPDATE Cartela 
        SET {} = %s
        WHERE PONTOS = %s""".format(campo)  # unsafe
atualiza = valor, jogador
cursor.execute(sql, atualiza)
```

---

As a safety check, make sure that the value of `campo` is the name of one of the columns of the table, except `PONTOS` or any of the import key columns. Better to check that it's in a white-list of column that you want to allow updating.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the `int - 2` is the problem here . 
Try this out :

Make your `SQL-query` this :

```
sql = """
    UPDATE Cartela 
    SET %s = CAST(%s AS int)
    WHERE PONTOS = %s
"""
```

And where you're calling the method `atualizaCartelaTabela` make it this :

```
atualizaCartelaTabela('Um','2','Jogador 1')
```